# WPF MeshGeometry3D image scaling is blurry

Tags: wpf, image, 3d, scaling, mesh

Context: I am trying to render Minecraft characters in WPF to preview skins. These skins are extremely tiny, such as the skin for the head I am trying to get working is 8x8 pixels.

Currently when I slap on the texture onto the mesh, it will render fine but the scaling makes it extremely blurry. I need it to scale in such a way that it doesn't try and 'smooth out' the scaling as the pixels are meant to be crisp lines. I couldn't find any properties on the `ImageBrush` that could help me with this result. My XAML:

```
<ModelVisual3D>
    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
        <GeometryModel3D>
            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,1 -1,-1,1 1,-1,1 1,1,1" TriangleIndices="0,1,2 0,2,3" TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0"/>
            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial>
                    <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/SteveHead.png" />
                    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                </DiffuseMaterial>
            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
        </GeometryModel3D>
    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
</ModelVisual3D>
```

This is the texture for the head (it's really here, just tiny :p) [image: The 8x8 Head]

And the result I am getting with this XAML: [image: The result with scaling]

Any tips so I can scale this up with the 'pixels' intact?